# Protecting and hiding sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro where I get a spreadsheet, hide all sheets and protect it. The hiding part is working perfectly. But the protecting part isn't. Here's my code:

```
  Dim sh As Worksheet

  For Each sh In Worksheets

    If sh.Name <> "Simulador" Then sh.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    sh.Protect Password:="123"

  Next
```

Does anyone know where I might be going wrong?

Comment: welcome to Stackoverflow. I think others will be interested to know you have tried searching for the answer already. You may add links that have partially helped you so far, so others know you have made an effort to find a solution. Microsoft documentation can be difficult sometimes, but that's where the answer lies in this case.

Comment: First link in google... https://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/protect-unprotect-worksheets/  Seems you might be missing parameter values

Comment: `But the protecting part isn't.` What do you mean by "Not Working"?. What error are you getting i.e if you are getting one... It works for me i.e it protects the sheet

Comment: Are you expecting it to protect the workbook or worksheets?

Comment: Do you want to protect the *Simulador* worksheet? Are you **absolutely** sure that there is **always** a *Simulador* worksheet in the workbook?

Comment: Seemed to work for me - hide all the sheets except Simulador and applied password protection to _all_ sheets.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks to all that replied. What happens is that doens't prevent someone to unhide the sheets. Sorry if this is a very basic question, but thanks to all that are trying to help.

Comment: If you want to prevent unhiding, instead of `xlSheetHidden` use `xlVeryHidden`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent users from unhiding a hidden sheet, you need to protect the Workbook structure

Try this:

```
    Sub TEST()
        With ThisWorkbook
            .Sheets("Simulador").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
            .Protect Password:="PassKey", Structure:=True
        End With
        End Sub
```

Setting the visibility of the sheet to `xlSheetVeryHidden` only still can be undone using vba.

See the following page:
[Workbook.Protect Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/excel-vba/articles/workbook-protect-method-excel)

Answer (score 1):

Your code does pretty much the equivalent of hiding sheets by rightclicking. This can be undone by rightclicking again and unhiding. Instead, you can use:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet

  For Each sh In Worksheets

    If sh.Name <> "Simulador" Then sh.Visible = xlVeryHidden
    sh.Protect Password:="123"

  Next
```

Please bear in mind that to undo a VeryHidden sheet, you'll have to do it with VBA: `sh.Visible = True`